# How do I change iPad lock screen font

Tags: ipad, font, ipados, lockscreen

I update my iPad (gen 8) to the newest iPad operating system today (iPadOS 16.1) and noticed that Apple has changed the default lock screen font used for the time. I’m not a big fan of the new font is there a way to change it?

[image: new lock screen font]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPadOS does not support lock screen customization as of version 16.1

Comment: I’m disappointed, but not surprised to hear that. Though I am surprised that apple would change the font without having font options.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're surprised. It's not the first time they've done it, by a long shot. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography_of_Apple_Inc.#System_fonts

Comment: Is was apparently possible to change the font during the Beta, but the solution does not work anymore as far as I can tell. See https://www.reddit.com/r/ipad/comments/v8t8sb/ipados_16_new_lock_screen_font/ibsfs7u/

Comment: so weird given you can on the iphone.